# makeRenderPipelineState failed [output of type ushort is not compatible with a MTLPixelFormatR16Float color attachement.]

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, metal, realitykit

I'm trying to present some text using realitykit, the code compiles, the scene starts but however no text is shown in the scene.

I'm using an iPhone 7 running iOS 13.1.2, i tried the same code but with a box Mesh Resource and it works just fine.

My controller looks like this

```
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {

        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)

        let anchor = AnchorEntity(plane: .horizontal)

        let mesh = MeshResource.generateText("text")
        let color = UIColor.systemBlue
        let material = UnlitMaterial(color: color)
        let entity = ModelEntity(mesh: mesh, materials: [material])

        anchor.addChild(entity)

        // Add the box anchor to the scene
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)

        return arView

    }
```

As i said before when i get to runtime the console show these errors:

```
2019-10-02 09:07:33.707275+0200 tesss[646:78901] Compiler failed to build request
2019-10-02 09:07:33.707476+0200 tesss[646:78901] [Graphics] makeRenderPipelineState failed [output of type ushort is not compatible with a MTLPixelFormatR16Float color attachement.].
2019-10-02 09:07:33.707507+0200 tesss[646:78901] [Graphics] makeRenderPipelineState failed.
```

Comment: What is your xcode version?

Comment: Version 11.0 (11A420a)

Comment: I started getting this error too for no apparent reason. One morning the app was working, the next it started complaining with the above errors. I fixed it by installing the latest iOS on my device, errors all of a sudden went away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the `MeshResource.generateText` method uses a system font which is very large by default so you need to resize it. There are two ways to do this:

**1) Resize entity:**

```
entity.scale = SIMD3<Float>(0.01, 0.01, 0.1)
```

**2) Change font size:**

```
let mesh = MeshResource.generateText(
            "text", 
            extrusionDepth: 0.1,
            font: .systemFont(ofSize: 0.1),
            containerFrame: CGRect.zero,
            alignment: .left,
            lineBreakMode: .byTruncatingTail)
```

Comment: How do you specify the color? I am having a similar issue with SimpleMaterials.Sphere and I suspect its because the color is UIColor.systemblue.